# LM358P Op Amp Output Stays High

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to PWM lights with Arduino and IRF3205 N-channel MOSFET.

For fully turning the MOSFET on I am using this circuit. The op amp (datasheet [here](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/22771/STMICROELECTRONICS/LM358P.html)) and load are powered by a single 12V source (lead acid battery).

[image: Circuit]

(MOSFET has 100k pulldown resistor at gate, not shown in circuit)

Now the output stays high even when I manually connect inverting input to +12V and non-inverting input to ground. I tried three ICs and they are not damaged so it is not the IC. It is so frustrating.

Only way that the MOSFET turns off is when I short gate and source together.
Then it turns on slowly during 1 sec and stays on until I short those pins again.

The MOSFET turns off after the IC is removed from the IC socket.

Comment: Show all power rails. Show that mosfet source ground point connects to op-amp ground. Link to a data sheet for the op-amp.

Comment: They ask you for a complete schematic because words are too easy to misunderstand when discussing circuits.

Comment: SE provides you with a circuit designer that you can used from any browser.

Comment: The link to the datasheet needs to be edited into the post, not posted as a comment. I've edited it in.

Comment: If the MOSFET has a pull-down resistor on the gate, that should be shown on the schematic - the note in your question could easily be missed by someone viewing the schematic.  The schematic must be an accurate representation of your circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Your negative image is hard to see. The opamp has no pin numbers.

Is the opamp a fake LM358 from ebay? Or did you connect the opamp pins backwards?